# How to edit invoice template on Odoo15

Tags: odoo, invoice

I created custom fields in Odoo v15.

**PROBLEM**

Now I would like to add them to invoice template.

How I could do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit the form view (account.invoice.form) and add your custom fields to the view. Or if you want to test the view you can enable debug mode and click "Edit FormView" at the top right of your form view to (temporarily) edit the form view directly.

See my example below:

```
<record id="account_invoice_form_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.form.custom</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <field name="partner_id" position="after">
                <field name="custom_field"/>  
            </field>
        </field>
</record>
```